# Setting FUEL_ENV for a crontab

Tags: php, bash, cron, fuelphp

I'm trying to setup a cron for a task to run under FuelPHP while setting the environment.

```
/bin/bash FUEL_ENV=development /usr/local/bin/php /home/net/###DIR###/oil refine TaskName 2>&1
```

However I get the following error everytime.

```
/bin/bash: FUEL_ENV=development: No such file or directory
```

I'm not an expert at setting up cron jobs but is there something I am missing here? (The task on it's own run from the command line using the same command works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the fix:

```
/bin/bash -c "FUEL_ENV=development; /usr/local/bin/php /home/net/###DIR###/oil refine TaskName 2>&1"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler command line, you can use the `env` utility:

```
env FUEL_ENV=development /usr/local/bin/php ...
```